# Общее кратное число, оптимизация

Tags: java

Есть программа, которая работает, но числа long очень долго думает, а иногда и не все выписывает. Условия : программа должна работать пока не вводится 0 или число меньше нуля, программа должна из двух чисел посчитать их самый большой множитель и самое меньшее кратное число. Так вот, кратное число программа не всегда выписывает и я не понимаю почему. А ещё она очень долго думает. Можно ли как-то этот процесс ускорить? Хочу попросить не сильно переделывать программу.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class DelitelNasobek {
static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean ok = true;
    do{
    int number = sc.nextInt();
    if(number>0){
        int number2 = sc.nextInt();
        int min=number, max=number2;
    if(number>number2){
        max=number;
        min=number2;
    }
    for (long i = min; i >= 1; i--) {
        if(number%i==0 && number2%i==0){
            System.out.print(i + " ");
            break;
        }
    }
    for (long i = max; i <=min*max ; i+=max) {
        if(i%number==0 && i%number2==0){
            System.out.print(i);
            break;
        }
    } 
        System.out.println("");
    }else ok = false;
    }while(ok); 
}
```

}

Comment: Для каких чисел не работает?

Comment: которые большие очень, например 652314578, это ещё инт но работает так себе.

Comment: А второе какое? Может наименьшее общее кратное в `int` не влезает?

Comment: @talex Ну да, не влезит, поэтому у меня там long.

Answer (score 3):

1. Используем алгоритм Евклида для подсчёта наибольшего общего делителя.
2. Первое число делим на gcd и умножаем на второе. Именно в таком порядке, чтобы по возможности избежать переполнения.